# How to get access to appRouter's params and getServerSideProps's props at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13

I'm trying to make an api call to the backend to scrape some data based on the string the user provided. Based on the NextJS docs I should use getServerSideProps for this case so I tried to. The problem is the data returned from getServerSideProps is passed through the props of SearchResults, but my SearchResults is also receiving the keyword to search for through appRouter. `router.push(`/search/${keyword}`);`

How could I get access to both params and props at the same time?
I'm very new with NextJS, not even sure if this is the best way to do it. Any feedback/help is much appreciated.

Here's SearchResults's page.tsx

```
import React from "react";

const SearchResults = async ({ params }: { params: { keyword: string } }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Searching for {params.keyword}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(keyword: string) {
  const data = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/search/${keyword}`);
  const products = data.json();
  return { props: { products } };
}

export default SearchResults;
```

Tried to did some web searches on this problem but can't seem to find any.